# parsing xml using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlxml

Needed some help to parse text in Paragraph element in following XML in SQL server.

```
<FlowDocument PagePadding="5,5,5,5" Name="RTDocument" AllowDrop="True" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">   
  <Paragraph>Licence Number: 04467</Paragraph>
  <Paragraph>Licence Number: 3535333</Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

Please share any queries you may have.

Thank you

Comment: below is the XML   <FlowDocument PagePadding="5,5,5,5" Name="RTDocument" AllowDrop="True" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
<Paragraph>Licence Number: 04467</Paragraph><Paragraph>Licence Number: dddd</Paragraph></FlowDocument>

Comment: Please put the XML in your question, not in the comments. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @SidharthSoneja if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is: (If they have the same namespace)

```
;with xmlnamespaces(default 'schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation')
select @xml.value('(/FlowDocument/Paragraph)[1]', 'varchar(max)') + ' ' + 
    @xml.value('(/FlowDocument/Paragraph)[2]', 'varchar(max)')
```

Another way:

```
select data.col.value('(*:Paragraph)[1]','varchar(100)') 
    + ' ' +  data.col.value('(*:Paragraph)[2]','varchar(100)') as ParamName
FROM @xml.nodes('(*:FlowDocument)') as data(col)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or (complementing Roberto answer)

```sql
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation')

SELECT  FlowDocument.Paragraph.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)')
FROM    @xml.nodes('//FlowDocument/Paragraph') AS FlowDocument(Paragraph)
```

If has many Paragraph tags