# XML parsing with namespace SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are cleaning up data in our database and a column has XML details inside of  it which we want to be able to convert into plain text.

Below is the sample XML in the table column.

```
 <FlowDocument PagePadding="5,5,5,5" Name="RTDocument" AllowDrop="True" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
     <Paragraph>FILE DESTROYED - MAY 21st, 2008</Paragraph>
     <Paragraph>todo</Paragraph>
 </FlowDocument>
```

I am using this query, but it is not rendering the desired output due to the presence of Namespace (if I remove the namespace from the XML, I am able to render the output successfully).

```
SELECT  
    CAST(CAST(Comments AS XML).query('data(/FlowDocument/Paragraph)') AS VARCHAR(7000)) AS activity 
FROM 
    dbo.Activities
WHERE 
    ActivityID = 1
```

Kindly help in this matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can also declare your namespace like this:

```
;WITH xmlnamespaces(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation')
SELECT
CAST(CAST(Comments AS XML).query('data(/FlowDocument/Paragraph)') AS VARCHAR(7000)) AS activity 
FROM [dbo].Activities where ActivityID=1
```

Other options are given here: [parsing xml using sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754878/parsing-xml-using-sql-server/35755997#35755997)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use namespace declaration in your Query as per: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx

so your query portion would look something like:

```
query('
declare namespace NS="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
data(/NS:FlowDocument/NS:Paragraph)
')
```

Comment: You are very welcome. Please consider accepting the answer.